# Заполнить таблицу несколькими классами

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

У меня есть таблица с 4 столбцами `Is selected`, `name`, `path`, `size`.

```
        public class MyDataGrid
        {
            public CheckBox CheckBox { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public int Size { get; set; }
        }
```

А ещё есть класс с вложенными классами, данные которых надо занести в таблицу.

```
        public class FolderInfos
            {
                public class My_Folder
                {
                    public static string Name { get; } = "My Folder";
                    public static string Path { get; } = Path.MyFolder();
                    public static int Size { get; } = Convert.ToInt32(FileActions.DirSize(new DirectoryInfo(Path.MyFolder())));
                    public static CheckBox checkBox { get; } = new CheckBox();
                }
                 ......    
            }
```

Вопрос: Как правильно всё занести в таблицу, чтобы потом вытащить из таблицы отмеченные чекбоксы и выполнить определённый код?

Пытался сделать вот так:

```
        MyDataGrid myfolder = new MyDataGrid();
        myfolder.CheckBox = FolderInfos.My_Folder.checkBox;
        myfolder.Name = FolderInfos.My_Folder.Name;
        myfolder.Path = FolderInfos.My_Folder.Path;
        myfolder.Size = FolderInfos.My_Folder.Size;

        MyDataGrid.Items.Add(myfolder);
```

Comment: `Как правильно всё занести в таблицу` - наверно, избавиться от вложения, избавиться от дубликата кода, оооооочень тщательно продумать еще раз структуру проекта, ну а затем все это привязать к XAML, а не использовать создание контролов в коде (ужас!)...

Comment: `public class DataGrid` переназовите класс. У вас конфликт названия класса с контролом `DataGrid`. Из-за этого вообще ничего непонятно, что вам нужно.

Comment: `MyDataGrid.Items.Add(myfolder);` переведу на русский эту строчку кода - "обратиться к статическому свойству `Items` моего собственного класса `MyDataGrid` и вызвать его метод `Add` передав ему в качестве аргумента экземпляр класса `MyDataGrid` по ссылке `myfolder`". Быть может вам так станет понятнее, что происходит, а для меня это полная бессмыслица, у вас просто нет в коде выше статического свойства `Items` в классе `MyDataGrid`.